# Unable to authenticate on SharePoint Online using the BizTalk SharePoint adapter

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk, sharepoint-online, biztalk-2013

I have the following issue when using BizTalk 2013 ("R1") and SharePoint Online:

I have a static send port configured to add data to one specific list in a list in a SharePoint Online environment.

I have authentication setup using the username and password and I'm 100% sure this is a correct username and password. I'm able to login using the same credentials via a browser without problem.

FYI: the account used is a "Microsoft" only account, so **not** listed as an organizational (work/school) account as well.

Whenever I try to send something to the list, I get the following error:

```
A message sent to adapter "Windows SharePoint Services" on send port "SP_SharePointOnline" with URI "wsss://company.sharepoint.com:443/sites/poc/Biztalk-Demo/TR/Lists/List%%201" is suspended. 

Error details: [System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException] The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive location or send port with URI wsss://company.sharepoint.com:443/sites/poc/Biztalk-Demo/TR/Lists/List%%201.

Windows SharePoint Services adapter event ID: 12310
```

I have enabled WCF and WIF tracing in the BizTalk BTSNTSvc.exe and BTSNTSvc.exe.config as follows:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="Microsoft.IdentityModel" switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="wif" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="wcf" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="C:\logs\WCF64.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="wcf" />
  <add initializeData="C:\logs\WIF64.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="wif" />
</sharedListeners>
```

I get WCF logging, but I don't have any WIF logging (as I would expect).

The WCF logging provided the following as to why the channel faults (extract from WCF Trace Viewer):

```
<S:Fault>
<S:Code>
<S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value>
<S:Subcode>
<S:Value>wst:FailedAuthentication</S:Value>
</S:Subcode>
</S:Code>
<S:Reason>
<S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Authentication Failure</S:Text>
</S:Reason>
<S:Detail>
<psf:error>
<psf:value>0x80048821</psf:value>
<psf:internalerror>
<psf:code>0x80041012</psf:code>
<psf:text>The entered and stored passwords do not match.
</psf:text>
</psf:internalerror>
</psf:error>
</S:Detail>
</S:Fault>
```

As said: I'm 100% sure this is the correct username and password!
I'm stuck here, anyone able to help me out or point me in the right direction?

Why don't I have any WIF logging?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your URL. what if you try to use in the utl the link to your sharepoint site and the name of your List as "Destination Folder URL".

you can check [this](http://jpsmit.bloggingabout.net/2013/01/24/biztalk-server-2013-sharepoint-adapter-walkthrough/) walkthrough

Comment: The problem seems to be an issue with authentication with Microsoft Online, which occurs even before actually going to SharePoint.

The tool [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx) actually has the same issue.

FYI: I tried another SharePoint Online site in the meantime, which works fine.